# Using ASCII control codes in componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: ios

I have a need to separate a string based on an ASCII control character (in particular, a US — 0x1F).

How can I achieve this with `NSString componentsSeparatedByString` when it expects a unicode string and I'm providing ASCII (UTF-8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the literals:

```
[@"XXX\x1fYYY" componentsSeparatedByString:@"\x1f"]
```

or, better:

```
[@"XXX\x1fYYY" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]]
```

The ASCII control characters 00 - 1f are mapped to the same unicode code points.

Comment: Initially didn't work, but I suspect the source data didn't encode the 0x1F correctly. Works perfectly now — thanks!